# Using paste to create logical expression for data frame subset

Tags: r, subset

I have two dataframes, `remove` and `dat` (the actual dataframe). `remove` specifies various combinations of the factor variables found in `dat`, and how many to sample (`remove$cases`).

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(83)
dat <- data.frame(RateeGender=sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 1500, replace = TRUE), 
                  RateeAgeGroup=sample(c("18-39", "40-49", "50+"), size = 1500, replace = TRUE),
                  Relationship=sample(c("Direct", "Manager", "Work Peer", "Friend/Family"), size = 1500, replace = TRUE),
                  X=rnorm(n=1500, mean=0, sd=1),
                  y=rnorm(n=1500, mean=0, sd=1),
                  z=rnorm(n=1500, mean=0, sd=1))
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to read in a row from `remove` and use it to subset `dat`.  My current approach looks like:

```
remove <- expand.grid(RateeGender = c("Male", "Female"), 
                      RateeAgeGroup = c("18-39","40-49", "50+"),
                      Relationship = c("Direct", "Manager", "Work Peer", "Friend/Family"))
remove$cases <- c(36,34,72,58,47,38,18,18,15,22,17,10,24,28,11,27,15,25,72,70,52,43,21,27)

# For each row of remove (combination of factor levels:)
for (i in 1:nrow(remove)) {
  selection <- character()
  # For each column of remove (particular selection):
  for (j in 1:(ncol(remove)-1)){
    add <- paste0("dat$", names(remove)[j], ' == "', remove[i,j], '" & ')
    selection <- paste0(selection, add)
  }
  selection <- sub(' & $', '', selection) # Remove trailing ampersand
  cat(selection, sep = "\n") # What does selection string look like?
  tmp <- sample(dat[selection, ], size = remove$cases[i], replace = TRUE)
}
```

The output from `cat()` while the loop runs looks right, for example: `dat$RateeGender == "Male" & dat$RateeAgeGroup == "18-39" & dat$Relationship == "Direct"` and if I paste that into `dat[dat$RateeGender == "Male" & dat$RateeAgeGroup3 == "18-39" & dat$Relationship == "Direct" ,]`, I get the right subset.

However, if I run the loop as written with `dat[selection, ]`, each subset only returns `NAs`. I get the same outcome if I use `subset()`.  Note, I have `replace = TRUE` in the above solely because of the random sampling.  In the actual application, there will always be more cases per combination than required.

I know I can dynamically construct formulas for `lm()` and other functions using `paste()` in this way, but am obviously missing something in translating this into working with `[,]`.

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upvoted BrodieG's answer before I realized it doesn't do what you wanted in situations wehre the size of the category is smaller than the number of samples desired. (In fact his method doesn't really do sampling at all, but I think it is is an elegant solution to a different question so I'm not reversing my vote. And you could use a similar split strategy as illustrated below with that data.frame as the input.).

```
sub <- lapply( split(dat, with(dat, paste(RateeGender,  # split vector
                                          RateeAgeGroup,
                                          Relationship, sep="_")) ), 
             function (d) { n=  with(remove, remove[
                                      RateeGender==d$RateeGender[1]&
                                      RateeAgeGroup==d$RateeAgeGroup[1]& 
                                      Relationship==d$Relationship[1], 
                                                             "cases"])
                                      cat(n); 
                                      sample(d, n, repl=TRUE) } )
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use character expressions as you describe to subset either with `[` or `subset`.  If you wanted to do that you would have to construct the entire expression, and then use `eval`.  That said, there is a better solution using `merge`.  For example, let's get all the entries in `dat` that match the first two rows from `remove`:

```
merge(dat, remove[1:2,])
```

If we want all the rows that don't match those two, then:

```
subset(merge(dat, remove[1:2,], all.x=TRUE), is.na(cases))
```

This is assuming you want to join on the columns with the same names across the two tables.  If you have a lot of data you should consider using `data.table` as it is very fast for this type of operation.